# How to add a raw `.html` file to my react app

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I've been asked to add a `.html` file named `3x4mple.html` to my react app to verify my site to a third-party service.

The complete insides of the file looks like this:

```
site-verification: 3x4mple
```

How would I add this `.html` file to my site so I could access it raw from  `website.com/3x4mple.html` (with no unnecessary components on elements like `<head>` or
`<body>`)?

### My attempt.

I've only been able to get this to work on locally served versions.

For my attempt, I added the file to `/public` by forcefully adding it with `git add -f public/website.com/3x4mple.html`.

When I build and then `gatsby serve` and go to `localhost:9000/3x4mple.html` it works - however, when I push it to production and access the page I'm met with a `404` page.

How would I add a raw accessable `.html` file to my Gatsby app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be adding files to the `/static` folder.

Info available here: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/gatsby-project-structure/#folders

The `/public` folder is meant to be generated automatically when building the site and should be added to `.gitignore`

Files added to the `/static` folder will be copied to `/public` when building the site so it should have the same effect.

More information here: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/static-folder/